# Why do I have to put a dot before module when import it from the module within same directory?

Tags: python, python-import

I am learning Python and feel import function is some different from that of Java.

I have a code hierarchy like below:

- `./test.py`

  ```
  import pack
  ```
- `./pack/__init__.py`

  ```
  from . import submod
  ```
- `./pack/submod.py`

  ```
  from .anothersubmod import res
  ```
- `./pack/anothersubmod.py`

  ```
  res="something..."
  ```

`test.py` runs as above. When I re-write `submod.py` as:

```
from anothersubmod import res
```

Python gives me an error saying `anothersubmod` can not be found...

I guess `submod` and `anothersubmod` are in same directory thus they shall refer to each other with their module (file) name, why should I have to add a dot before `anothersubmod`?

Comment: I'd recommend reading e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Ok at least got something working, so why asking

Comment: it works in terms of test.py. But  if I run submod.py alone, python gives error again until I emove dot ahead of anothersubmod. This does not make sense. Do I have to modify import everytime I load module from different context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java equivalent would be to explicitly reference `pack` everywhere, like:

```
import pack.anothersubmod.MyClass;
```

The Python equivalent of that would be:

```
from pack.anothersubmod import MyClass
```

That is correct Python and actually preferred style. Python also has the ability to use relative paths in import statements (`from .` style), but they tend to cause more confusion.

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#imports) recommends using absolute imports everywhere whenever possible:

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured.

Comment: Relative path of import do confuse me. I will follow PEP8's recommendation ^_^